# Keycloak: Importing realm.json error because of declarative-user-profile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I am using keyclaock in docker compose file and try to import realm.json file as mentioned below but importing realm fails with this error

```
15:07:38,919 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) KC-SERVICES0005: Unable to import realm boost from file /opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config/keycloak-realm.json.: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such provider 'declarative-user-profile'
```

Code from docker compose

```
keycloak:
image: 'wizzn/keycloak:14'
environment:
  KEYCLOAK_IMPORT: /opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config/keycloak-realm.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
volumes:
  - ./keycloak-init:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config
```

Comment: Do you need to pass -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.declarative_user_profile=enabled ?

Comment: No, Where should I pass it ?

Comment: Not sure, i think it is under keycloak: the field command: -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled  -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.declarative_user_profile=enabled

Comment: Did you tried it out?